# How to check the collection having a relation in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, collections

We already know,
check the data type is that an array can use the php `is_array` to get the answer,
but, how we check a Collection that have a relation (hasMany)? 

here is the code:
1:

```
User::where('name','alex')->first();
```

2:

```
User::where('name','alex')
    ->with(['article' => function($q){
         $q->where('active', 1);
    }])->first();
```

A function need to accept those kind data to do somthing,
and I need to know which one have a relation

Comment: Put some codes for a better understanding of what you mean.

Comment: OK , I`m fetch it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are referring to [`getRelations()`](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_getRelations) method:

```
$user = User::where('name', 'alex')->first();
// If user has some relations loaded (obviously not here)
if ($user->getRelations()) {

}
```